# Insert all files from directory into table (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use the following snippet to insert single files.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files]
    (Data, Name)
    (SELECT *, 'test.test' FROM 
    OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\test.test', SINGLE_BLOB) as Data)  
GO
```

Is there a way to do that with all files and keeping their filenames? Like:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files]
    (Data, Name)
    (SELECT *, <FILENAME> FROM 
    OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\*.*', SINGLE_BLOB) as Data)        
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLCMD to generate and run a script that does insert for each file in *some* folder.

Some explainations:

> :r = run specified script
>
> :!! = run dos batch command

For testing you might want to remove the two last the line with the :r command and the line that deletes big_script.sql.

Create a stored procedure that wraps the insert statement (this is mainly to make this sqlcmd script easier to debug and read).
Create a file named main.sql in the same folder as your txt-files. Add the following content to this script.

I do not have access to a sql server machine right now so I have not been able to test this particular version of it. There might be minor bugs but the overall idea should work.

main.sql:

```
:!! if exist big_script.sql del big_script.sql
:!! for %f in (*.test) do @(echo EXEC dbo.ImportFile @File = %f &echo.GO)>> big_script.sql
:r big_script.sql

:!! del big_script.sql
```

Run it like this:

```
sqlcmd -E -S REMOTESERVERNAME -d DATABASENAME -i main.sql
```

Comment: Would it be possible to run this within MS SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: I honestly cannot remember. There is an option within the QUERY-meny of SSMS where you specify that the script is a SQLCMD script, you can try if that works. You would need to specify the location of the files with a explicit path

Comment: In the end I used a similar solution. A powershell script just generates the `.sql` file.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it quite easily in SSIS. You would have to use For Each loop container and you can then insert the variable that contains the current file name anywhere you want using a Exec SQL task.

Here is a clear explanation of processing multiple files using SSIS:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/

SSIS is very fast, has great logging, error handling and once you are moderately comfortable with it, is very flexible.

Comment: SSIS is not an option.